# django registration/login views using @login_required decorator

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to create a separate register view for user, but it doesn't work since I am using the @login_required decorator on my 'profile' view, which is should redirect to after signing in. Currently the login_user view works fine.

QUESTION: How can I register the user while using the @login_required decorator on 'profile' view?

My code looks like this for the login and registration view:

```
def login_user(request):
  message = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'login' in request.POST:
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if not user:
                message = "Invalid email or password!"
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('profile')
  return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'message': message})


def register_user(request):
  message = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        user = authenticate(username=user_form.cleaned_data['email'],
                            password=user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        message = "Email already exists or passwords do not match"
  return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'message': message})
```

In order for my registration page to get around the @login_required decorator I used the login(request, user) method, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Which part is not working? What is the difference between `profile` and `profile_card`?

Comment: It should be profile for both views. Just edited that piece, thanks! Nonetheless, that doesn't make a difference in the code. When the user logs in they are redirected to the 'profile' page; however, when the user registers they are redirected to the login page, because of the @login_required decorator on the 'profile' view. So, basically I want to be able to register a user and get redirected to the 'profile' page, not the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the backend as a third argument to the login function.
So in your register_user function:

```
if user:
    # specify the backend as the third argument
    login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    return redirect('profile')
```